# Character encoding fail, why does \xBD display improperly in PHP + HTML

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm just trying to understand character encoding a bit better, so I'm doing a few tests.

I have a PHP file that is saved as UTF-8 and looks like this:

```
<?php
declare(encoding='UTF-8');

header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
?><!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php echo "\xBD"; # Does not work ?>
    <?php echo htmlentities( "\xBD" ) ; # Works ?>
</body>

</html>
```

The page itself shows this:

[image]

The gist of the problem is that my web application has a bunch of character encoding problems, where people are copying and pasting from Outlook or Word and the characters get transformed into the diamond question marks (Do those have a real name?)

I'm trying to learn how to make sure all my input is transformed into UTF-8 when the page loads (Basically `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_REQUEST`), and all output is done using proper UTF-8 handling methods.

---

My question is: Why is my page showing the question mark for the first echo, and does anyone have any other information about making a UTF-8 safe web app in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0xBD is not valid UTF-8. If you want to encode "½" in UTF-8 then you need to use 0xC2 0xBD instead.

```
>>> print '\xc2\xbd'.decode('utf-8')
½
```

If you want to use text from another charset (Latin-1 in this case) then you need to transcode it to UTF-8 first using the various iconv or mb functions.

Also:

```
$ charinfo �
U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER
```

Answer (score 2):

`\xBD` is not valid as utf8 what you want is `\xC2\xBD`, the question mark thing is what applications replace invalid code points with, so if you see that in your utf8 text its either not utf8 or corrupted.