# Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb, laravel-5.5

I'm getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xBD Inch...' for column 'column-name' at row 1

My database, table, and column have the format **utf8mb4_unicode_ci** also column-name is type *text* and *NULL*.

This is the value of the column-name

> [column-name] => Some text before 11 ▒ and other text after, and after.

However I wait that laravel adds quotes to column's values, because the values are separated by commas (,). It should be as follow:

> [column-name] => 'Some text before 11 ▒ and other text after, and after.'

See below the Schema

```
    Schema::create('mws_orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('custom-id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('comment')->nullable();
        $table->integer('count')->nullable();
        $table->text('column-name')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->primary('custom-id');
    });
```

I have been looking for on google but not any solution, yet.

Anyone has an idea how to solve this issue?

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and MariaDB 10.2.11.

Comment: Possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553124/character-encoding-fail-why-does-xbd-display-improperly-in-php-html

Comment: Looks like the column is supposed to be date time format, not a string. check your schema.

Comment: The problem looks like other, Laravel is not enclosing into quotes. There are commas in my string. The insert error shows column's names with backtick, but column's values don't have quotes.

Comment: Laravel uses parameter binding, which does not quote the values. Show your database schema and the exact code you're using.

Comment: I'm using instance of my Model to insert $myModel = new MyModel();  $myModel->insert($data); when you talk about schema, do you refer to migration?

Comment: Yes, that will work. Make sure you [edit] your question with the code, instead of putting it in a comment.

Comment: I added the table's Schema to question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I solved it, encoding to uft-8 all string columns that generated this error before insert. For example, the column that generated the error was **column-name**, I encoded as show bellow. Also I found other column with the same error, I used this solution, too.

```
$data [
//key=>values 
];

$myModel = new MyModel(); 

$data['column-name'] = DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote(utf8_encode($data['column-name']));

$myModel->insert($data);
```

Comment: just adding the utf8_encode() method did it for me. Quoting everything literally saved my values with quotes

Answer (score 21):

I ran into similar problems with Laravel 5.5 and MariaDB 10.2. When storing some user input t into a varchar column, an exception:

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\x86y\xE2\x80...' for column 'comment' at row 1

will be thrown.

Since this only happened on the stage server but not on local dev server, I compared the collation and charset of underlining table, it turns out database and table on stage server use latin1 while local dev server uses utf8mb4.

The problem was solved by changing database and table collation and char set to utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

```
ALTER DATABASE <db_name> CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

For anyone who runs into this problem, please check collation and char set of your database and table. Chances are Laravel app is encoding with utf8 while databases uses something else.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem, but my table charset/collation was correct. The culprit turned out to be a legacy call to `SET NAMES UTF8` that didn't get updated when we moved to utf8mb4.  Once I removed that call it worked fine. So if you're suffering from this issue, check to see if you have a stray call forcing the connection to an incorrect character set.

Answer (score 5):

If [mb-convert-encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) or [utf8-encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) are not solving this problem for you, check if you're only using **string functions in their multibyte variants**.

e.g.
Instead of `substr` you must use `mb_substr`

Doc reference here: [Multibyte String Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php)

Written for future readers who might end up with my same problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Just change database configuration **(charset & collation)** in

> config/database.php

to:

```
'connections' => [
        'mydb' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',              // **for emoticons**
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',   // **for emoticons**
        ],
]
```

Answer (score 2):

**follow this steps for solve problem**

1- **change CHARACTER and COLLATE`s  table**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

2-**change config /database.php  file**

```
 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',//****make sure these configs are set
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',//****make sure these configs are set
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
     
    ],
```

3- run this command to **regenerate config cache**

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 1):

`BD` is the latin1 (and several others) encoding for `½` (one-half).  The error message talks about storing that in a datetime.  So, it sounds like there are at least two errors --

- mismatch of `CHARACTER SETs`
- poorly formulated query

You show us something about the `CREATE TABLE`, but why would "inches" be involved in that?

Comment: The problem is really relate to missing quotes, I took the raw query, add quotes to each value  and run directly in the database, and inserted correctly. Now it turns to another question: why Laravel is missing quotes and how solve it?

Comment: Laravel is not missing quotes. It's using PDO, prepared statements and parameter binding, which bypasses the need for quotes.

Comment: Let's see the _generated SQL_.